# How to import CSV into Custom Post Type custom fields?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, import, csv

I have created a Custom Post Type and then used a plugin to create the custom fields for that post type.

It will display a type of membership:
Name
Address
Zip
Website

But I am stuck on how to take the csv file I have, which has 700 entries and import it to create 700 entries under the CPT I created and autopopulate the custom fields I created.

I tried a lot of plugins, but none seemed to do both parts. Some let me just select the CTP but I couldn´t get all the fields populated.

Just needed to know best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you try http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/ ? It took some work but that one worked for me.

Comment: Also - what plugin did you use to create the custom fields? I've noticed some custom-field-creating plugins prefix the custom field names and it's not obvious when that happens. Makes it hard to match the fields with their contents.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm using a plugin called **TurboCSV** ([found here](http://wphostreviews.com/product/turbocsv), at the time of writing). The plugin offers support to add data to your various custom fields, which need to be created before the import takes place. In my personal use, I was able to successfully import thousands of items from one **.csv**, including hundreds of taxonomy terms and custom fields.

Have a look at the [plugin's documentation](http://wphostreviews.com/turbocsv-documentation) to see how involved it is and how much you're able to do.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of custom fields, and the answer becomes useless if the specified link changes or is broken

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however, the plugin that I suggested can do custom fields, per the [documentation](http://wphostreviews.com/turbocsv-documentation). I understand the problem with the links being dead in the future, but given the context, a simple Google search can find what's needed.

Comment: You didn't explain that in your answer, and again as I said, you cant just post a link as an answer

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for the constructive criticism. I've updated my answer to reflect more info that better follows that it should be...at least I think I did.

Comment: Hello here from the future to say the link is in fact dead.

Comment: link is in fact 404!

Answer (score 9):

I used a plugin called Really Simple CSV Importer https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/

If that link is dead, you can find it on github here: https://github.com/dansullyLT/rs-csv-importer

It populated my custom fields that I made in ACF.

**Here is how I used it.**

Download the sample CSV file the plugin dev offers you. You make each header row the field name and import through the WordPress > Tools > Import menu.

You have to include a column of post_id and post_name, but you can leave them blank. Make the post_type column the name of your custom field group and set the post_status. You may get some errors on import, but just read them carefully and you'll be able to correct them.

It worked great for all of my ACF except images. My images were a little complicated though.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to WP.SE. Thanks for taking your time to share your knowledge. As you might have noticed from the accepted answer: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem (in code). Copy/Pasting from the plugins source is absolutely ok

Comment: I protest this comment. I did tell the person how to use this and I gave them hints. Please read my reply.

Comment: Ok, Dan. So you added a second link and explained _using_ a plugin. That might be a valid answer on SuperUser, but not really here. As I said: Copy/Paste from plugin source to at least sketch out a code solution is absolutely ok.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.wpallimport.com/

There's a free version of this plugin that should do all the necessary work to import Custom Post Types from a CSV or Excel file.

The paid versions also allow you to import users and to better modify advanced custom fields associated with CPT's as well.